# Failed to instantiate component or class "sizeg\jwt\JwtHttpBearerAuth"

Tags: php, yii2, jwt

Всем привет. Недавно начал работать с Yii2 и столкнулся с такой проблемой, при попытке использовании JWT токенов от sizeg. Делал всё по документации, внёс параметр в конфиги, добавил проверку в behaviors, но всё равно выдаёт данную ошибку. Может кто-то подсказать в какую сторону копать вообще?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как Вы устанавливали JWT ? через composer?

Comment: Да, устанавливал по доке https://github.com/sizeg/yii2-jwt

Comment: @zolotoi2012 А покажите конфиг сам в yii и behaviors в контролере . Плюс, как вариант, можно попробовать сделать composer dump-autoload, но я думаю, что проблема не в этом

Comment: @z1bun Добавил, в описание к проблеме) Дамп тоже сделал, но не помогло :с